# Data Size Limits for iCloud Document Storage

Tags: ios, icloud, uidocument

Is there a way to know if the iCloud document storage quota is exceeded?

Is there something similar to `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreQuotaViolationChange` key of `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification` notification for iCloud document storage?